# Select all fields from the table with multiset

Tags: java, sql, jooq

What is the best way to pass all fields to fetch table with multiset? If I have many fields in the table, then this method will be too large

```
return dsl.select(
                USER.asterisk(),
                multiset(
                    select(USER_ROLE.AUTHORITY_ID.as(ROLE.ID))
                        .from(USER_ROLE)
                        .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID)))
                    .as("roles")
                    .convertFrom(f -> f.intoSet(roleMapper)))
            .from(USER)
            .where(field.eq(value));
```

And will it be ok if my multiset returns `roles` and then I need to set it to the user in my record mapper?

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public User map(Record record) {
    final User user = new User();
    user.setId(record.get(USER.ID));
    user.setEmail(record.get(USER.EMAIL));
    user.setPassword(record.get(USER.PASSWORD));
    user.setFirstName(record.get(USER.FIRST_NAME));
    user.setLastName(record.get(USER.LAST_NAME));
    user.setActivated(record.get(USER.ACTIVATED));
    user.setActivationKey(record.get(USER.ACTIVATION_KEY));
    user.setImageUrl(record.get(USER.IMAGE_URL));

    final Set<Role> roles = Optional.ofNullable(record.get("roles"))
            .map(r -> (Set<Role>) r)
            .orElse(Collections.emptySet());

    user.setRoles(roles);
    user.setResetKey(record.get(USER.RESET_KEY));
    user.setResetDate(record.get(USER.RESET_DATE));
    user.setLastModifiedBy(record.get(USER.LAST_MODIFIED_BY));
    user.setLastModifiedDate(record.get(USER.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE));
    user.setLangKey(record.get(USER.LANG_KEY));

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all `USER` columns at once using [`record.into(USER)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#into(org.jooq.Table)):

```java
UserRecord userRecord = record.into(USER);
// And then, for example:
User user = userRecord.into(User.class);
```

You can even let jOOQ do all of that for you by projecting a nested `TableRecord` like this (since jOOQ 3.17, [`Table<R>` extends `SelectField<R>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/)):

```java
return dsl.select(
                USER,
                multiset(...)
            .from(USER)
            ...
```

This produces a `Record2<UserRecord, Result<...>>` type, so you already have all the `USER` columns in a handy nested record.

Comment: will it work in this case? For some reason, the fields were not set in CardRecord

Comment: `public Optional<Card> findById(Integer id) {
        return dsl.select(
                CARD,
                CARD.user().ID,
                CARD.user().FIRST_NAME,
                CARD.user().LAST_NAME,
                CARD.user().IMAGE_URL,
                CARD.user().EMAIL
            )
            .from(CARD)
            .where(CARD.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOptional(mapper);
    }`

Comment: sorry for format `public class CardRecordMapper implements RecordMapper<Record, Card> {

    @Override
    public Card map(Record record) {
        final CardRecord cardRecord = record.into(CARD);

        final Card card = new Card();
        card.setId(cardRecord.get(CARD.ID));`

Comment: @Moments: It's hard to answer a complex question from the comments. May I ask you to ask a new question instead?